# Razor View DateTime and Jquery DateTime

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

Perhaps its very easy but now i'm blocked.

```
@{
System.DateTime Bugun = new System.DateTime();}

$(document).ready(function () {


    var Bugun = new Date(@Bugun.Year, @Bugun.Month, @Bugun.Day, @Bugun.Hour, @Bugun.Minute, @Bugun.Second,@Bugun.Millisecond);
    console.log(new Date().getTime() + '-' + Bugun.getTime());
});

"1431974228146--2174781600000"
```

Why this results are not same?

Comment: Final solution is :
`code`
@{
 DateTime s = new DateTime();
    s = DateTime.Now;
    System.DateTime Bugun = new System.DateTime(s.Year, s.Month, s.Day, s.Hour, s.Minute, s.Second, s.Millisecond);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
      
        var Bugun = new Date(@Bugun.Year, @Bugun.Month, @Bugun.Day, @Bugun.Hour, @Bugun.Minute, @Bugun.Second,@Bugun.Millisecond);
        console.log(new Date().getTime() + '-' + Bugun.getTime());
    }); `code`

Answer (score 0):

Because default value for .net `DateTime` is 0:00:00 (midnight) on January 1, 0001 while date created using javascript parameteless contructor defaults to "now"

Comment: I'v tried this : 
DateTime s = new DateTime();
    System.DateTime Bugun = new System.DateTime(s.Year, s.Month, s.Day, s.Hour, s.Minute, s.Second, s.Millisecond);